# How to validate count of related documents?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I have two models Item and Tag

```
class Item
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :title, type: String
  has_many :tags

  validates_length_of :tags, minimum: 1
end

class Tag
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :title, type: String
  belongs_to :item
end
```

The Item must have minimum 1 tag.
When item is created validation works very well:

```
item = Item.create(title: "black hole")
item.tags << Tag.create(title: "black")
item.tags << Tag.create(title: "heavy")

puts item.valid? # => true
item.save
```

But validation fails when the existed item is modified:

```
item = Item.find(item.id)

item.title = "nothing"
puts item.tags.count # => 2, it's ok
puts item.valid? # => false, it's wrong
```

How  to validate count of related documents properly?

Comment: Can you do a quick check on `item.errors` to see if it's really the tags that are causing the validation error?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `attr_accessible` to title?

It would look like this:

```
class Item
  include Mongoid::Document

  attr_accessible :title # <-- here
  field :title, type: String
  has_many :tags

  validates_length_of :tags, minimum: 1
end
```